# Automake for shared libraries in all subdirectories

Tags: c++, autotools, autoconf, automake

I am currently working on a project, that looks like this:

```
root folder

|---plugin manager
|      |---plugin_manager.cpp
|      |---plugin_interface.hpp 
|
|---libraries
|
|---Plugins
|      |
|      |---Plugin1
|      |      |---Plugin1.cpp
|      |      |---Plugin1.hpp
|      |---Plugin2 
|      |      |---Plugin2.cpp
|      |      |---Plugin2.hpp
```

I am compiling a .so for each plug-in and then I "load" it with the plugin_manager. This works fine. I even created a simple makefile, which is able to compile a .so. Here are my make and config files:

configure.ac

```
AC_INIT(My Project, 0.1, my@email, myproject)
AC_PREREQ(2.68)
AC_COPYRIGHT(GNU General Public License)
AM_CONFIG_HEADER([config.h])

AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([m4])
AM_PROG_LIBTOOL
AC_PROG_INSTALL

AC_PROG_CXX
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([1.9 foreign])
AC_CONFIG_FILES(Makefile)
AC_ENABLE_SHARED
AC_DISABLE_STATIC
LT_INIT
AC_OUTPUT
```

Makefile.am

```
ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = -I m4
#Generating libtest.so
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libtest.la
#here you can list your source files
libtest_la_SOURCES = Plugin1.cpp
libtest_la_LDFLAGS = -module -avoid-version -export-dynamic
```

However, this make file is not that user-friendly, since I have to put it manually in each plug-in folder and also change its source files. That is why I want to create another one, which basically by typing make creates an executable in the plugin manager folder, as well as a .so in each plug-in folder. I have been reading for the last couple of days about autotools and tried implementing something similar to what the guys [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/makefiles-and-subdirectories-794088/) suggested, but it didn't work. So I hope that there is someone here, who has experience with such makefiles and can give me a tip on how to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Automake has limitations even with wildcards (http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Wildcards.html).

I do not thing that to do what you want is possible without using a bash script to generate your Makefile.am.

However, if using CMake is not a problem for you.
You should be able to do it with something like

```
FILE(GLOB dir_list "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Plugins/*")
FOREACH(dir_entry dir_list)
   FILE(GLOB file_src "${dir_entry}/*.cpp"
   add_library(plugin_${dir_entry} ${file_src})
ENDFOREACH(dir_entry dir_list)
```